# Call Contoller action method using angularjs $http service in DNN 8 mvc module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to call Contoller's action method using Angularjs.
Following is my View code.

```
@using DotNetNuke.Framework.JavaScriptLibraries
@using DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement
@{    
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(Dnn.DnnPage,                 "~/desktopmodules/mvc/DNNMVCModule/Scripts/angular.js");
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(Dnn.DnnPage, "~/desktopmodules/mvc/DNNMVCModule/Scripts/DnnMvcModule.js");
}

<h2 >DnnMvcModule Index</h2>
    <div id="Testdiv" ng-app="dataStore" >
        <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
            <h3>{{data.name}}</h3>
            <h3>{{data.surname}}</h3>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Herer is my angular js code.

```
(function () {
     var app = angular.module('dataStore', []);

     app.controller('StoreController', function ($scope, $http) {

     $http.get('/DnnMvcModule/GetData').
         success(function (response, status) {                
             $scope.data = response;
             alert(data.name);
          }).
          error(function (response, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.data = response;
              alert(data.cod);
          });
      });                   
})();
```

Here is my Contoller's action method.

```
public class DnnMvcModuleController : DnnController
{
    // GET: DnnMvcModule
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data = new Responsedata { name = "Chirag", surname = "Daraji" };
        return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

When i tried to call controller's GetData method using above code in response i am getting following error form DNN.

```
Error: DNNMVCModule is currently unavailable.
\r\n DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Object   reference not set to an instance of an object. --->       System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
\r\n at    DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Routing.StandardModuleRoutingProvider.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext, ModuleControlInfo moduleControl)
\r\n at DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.MvcHostControl.GetModuleRequestContext(HttpContextBase httpContext)\r\n at DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.MvcHostControl.OnInit(EventArgs e)
\r\n --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n\r\n\t
```

The same i have tried with normal MVC application its working fine.
Can some one help me what is going wrong with this.!?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided here I believe you need to expose a differen portion of the URL for the proper route. As the DNN mvc routing is a bit more complicated. Can you share your rout configuration.

Comment: HI Mitchel, Thanks for the reply. I have used Chris Hammond's MVC DNN 8 template  to create this project and there isn't any rout configuration file in this template. Like we do have in nomal MVC application project template. and there isn't any Global.asax file. :(